# What is the impact of using high X caps values on EMI filters in a DC DC converter?

Tags: filter, dc-dc-converter, emc, x-capacitor

I am working with traditional single stage EMI filter. I see CE EMI test passing with a high X cap values of 6.8 uF. This is used in DC DC converter with 8 kW power out at 400 V DC. I see no issue with high value of X caps! Can some one shed some light on impact of using very high value X caps on DC DC converter EMI filter.

Key points:

1. This is DC DC, so X caps do not produce loss.
2. Since we are talking abut X caps, They are connected between +Ve and -ve lines, hence leakage is not affected by increase of X cap values.
3. This DC DC converter -ve is not tied to P.E (FYI only).

Comment: They'll still produce loss due to ripple current.

Comment: If you pass your EMC test, then problem solved?

Comment: @Hearth, The majority of ripple will be observed by main CAP's, the ripple in this cap and losses from it is negligible , we are talking about 8KW power here, so i will not worry on losses from X caps,